# multiple bars in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot multiple bars over each other, with matplotlib.
I have used:

```
a=(45,22,17,28)

b=(32,17,15,27)

c=(15,18,22,25)

rects1 = plt.bar(index, a, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='b',error_kw=error_config,  label='A')

rects2 = plt.bar(index, b, bar_width,alpha=opacity, color='r', error_kw=error_config,   label='B',bottom=a)

rects4 = plt.bar(index , c, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='y', error_kw=error_config, label='C',bottom=a+b)
```

I would like to have c over b over a, but bottom=a+b doesn't work...

Comment: Use [`zorder`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html) to specify which plot lies over one another.

Comment: well, that doesn't work, because I want to have c in the top of b+a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you cannot add tuples. What you need are numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([45,22,17,28])

b=np.array([32,17,15,27])

c=np.array([15,18,22,25])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the configuration you are looking for:

You have to specify index c with a zorder > a and > b, i.e., (index c, ..., zorder=3); (index b, ..., zorder=2); (index a, ..., zorder=1). Your code should look like:

```
a=(45,22,17,28)

b=(32,17,15,27)

c=(15,18,22,25)

rects1 = plt.bar(index, a, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='b',error_kw=error_config, label='A', zorder=1)

rects2 = plt.bar(index, b, bar_width,alpha=opacity, color='r', error_kw=error_config, label='B', zorder=2)

rects4 = plt.bar(index, c, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='y', error_kw=error_config, label='C', zorder=3)
```